# ¿Cómo buscar un elemento en una lista enlazada desordenada?

Tags: c++, lista, funciones, busqueda

Tengo este código simple en C++ el cuál es de popular implementación y funciona sin errores:

```
template <class T>
int DList<T>::search(int buscar){
bool encontrado=false;
int i=0;
    Nodo *actual=new Nodo();
    actual=inicio;
    while ( (actual!=NULL) && (actual->dato<=buscar) )
    {
        actual=actual->siguiente;
        i++;
    }
    int ii = i-1;
    return ii;
}
```

Sin embargo, este solo trabaja en listas con números ordenados gracias a la condición <= de su while. Este arroja 0 si se busca el primer número, 1 si se busca el segundo y así sucesivamente. He tratado de modificarle pero nada funciona.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que funcione en una lista con datos desordenados como [2,1,5,3]

Answer (score 3):

Edito: perdona, la lógica habitual suele ser justo la opuesta.

Únicamente tienes que modificar la condición. Reemplaza `<=` por `!=`:

```
while ( (actual!=NULL) && (actual->dato!=buscar) )
//                                     ^^ AQUI
```

Lo que buscas es salir del bucle cuando llegues al final de la lista o encuentres el elemento que buscas.

Por otro lado necesitas eliminar la resta final:

```
while ( (actual!=NULL) && (actual->dato!=buscar) )
{
    actual=actual->siguiente;
    i++;
}
int ii = i-1; // <<--- AQUI
return ii;
```

También es importante que aprendas a usar los depuradores de código. No llegarás muy lejos si no aprendes a usar estas herramientas

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero el == realmente lo corrompe, puesto que la condición es que sea diferente al dato. Si se anexa un ==, el acumulador ni siquiera funciona y el resultado siempre es -1. Ahora, si se pone un != el programa lanza números aleatorios extraños de respuesta.

Comment: Asimismo, modificar la condición para que sólo dependa de un !=, que era mi plan inicial, lanza un segmentation fault.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. Cuando pongo el == y borro el ii para dejarlo en i, en absolutamente todos los casos da 0. Estás diciendo casos que ya utilicé y está peor que el principio.

Comment: El programa en si si funciona con lo que ya tiene, solo que quiero hacer que funcione para desorden sin que de segmentation fault, y el == y la i no hacen eso.

Comment: @MACP perdona, estaba con otros problemas y no me fijé bien

Comment: No hay problema :)

Comment: El (int buscar) que está dentro de la función recibe un número dentro de la lista y regresa su posición. Si mi lista fuese {1,2,3,4} y busco el 3, me regresa un 2 porque es su posición en la lista y eso está correcto. Sin embargo, si la lista es {1,2,6,4} y busco el 4, ya no manda 3 porque el while no cumple. La gran mayoría usa la característica del <= porque tiene sus listas ordenadas pero en mi caso no siempre es así. Por eso la duda :/